# Pandas dataframe puts NaN and NaT

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

What I'm doing is I have generated a DataFrame with pandas:

```
df_output = pd.DataFrame(columns={"id","Payout date", "Amount"}
```

In column 'Payout date' is a datetime, and in 'Amount' a float. I'm taking the values for each row from a csv:

```
df=pd.read_csv("file.csv", encoding = "ISO-8859-1", low_memory=False)
```

but when I assign the values:

```
df_output.loc[df_output['id'] == index, 'Payout date'].iloc[0]=(parsed_date)
pay=payments.get()
ref=refunds.get()
df_output.loc[df_output['id'] == index, 'Amount'].iloc[0]=(pay+ref-for_next_day)
```

and I print it the columns 'Payout date' and 'Amount' it only prints the id correctly, and NaT for the payouts and NaN for the amount, even when casting them to floats, or using

```
df_output['Amount']=pd.to_numeric(df_output['Amount'])
df_output['Payout date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_output['Payout date'])
```

I've also tried casting the values before passing them to the DataFrame, with no luck, so what I'm getting is this:

```
id Payout date  Amount
1         NaT     NaN
2         NaT     NaN
3         NaT     NaN
4         NaT     NaN
5         NaT     NaN
```

Instead, I'm looking for something like this:

```
id       Payout date  Amount
1         2019-03-11     3.2
2         2019-03-11     3.2
3         2019-03-11     3.2
4         2019-03-11     3.2
5         2019-03-11     3.2
```

EDIT

```
print(df_output.head(5))
print(df.head(5))

id Payout date  Amount
1         NaT     NaN
2         NaT     NaN
3         NaT     NaN
4         NaT     NaN
5         NaT     NaN

id       Created (UTC)    Type Currency  Amount    Fee     Net
1 2016-07-27 13:28:00  charge      mxn   672.0  31.54  640.46
2 2016-07-27 15:21:00  charge      mxn   146.0   9.58  136.42
3 2016-07-27 16:18:00  charge      mxn   200.0  11.83  188.17
4 2016-07-27 17:18:00  charge      mxn   146.0   9.58  136.42
5 2016-07-27 18:11:00  charge      mxn   286.0  15.43  270.57
```

Comment: Do you check that your columns are filled when you perform each step? When trouble shooting it is best to print each step where a new variable is assigned. For example, start by `print(df)`, then `print(df_output)` then `print(pay)` etc. I can imagine you will see an issue prior to your final df.

Comment: I have done that, both, the print pay will return the datetime correctly, also the amount is correct when printing it individually

Comment: Could you also include the head of your df?

Comment: What is the head? And the head of what df?

Comment: print(df.head(5)) prints the first 5 rows of a dataframe.

Comment: i updated the post, there are the 2 print heads

Comment: What are `parsed_date`, `payments`, `refunds` and `for_next_day`? Have you double checked their values? Can you provide a sample so your issue can be reproduced?

Comment: parsed_date is a string parsed into datetime, payments and refunds are queues, for next day is a variable which accumulates fees that affect the next day instead of the present day, i can give you the code, the files i cannot since they have sensitive data. And yes i have checked those variables, their type, even casted them to the type i wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest thing to do would be just to rename the columns of the dataframe you're loading:

```py
df = pd.read_csv("file.csv", encoding = "ISO-8859-1", low_memory=False, index_col='id')
df.columns(rename={"Created (UTC)":'Payout Date'}, inplace=True)

df_output = df[['Payout Date', 'Amount']]
```

EDIT:
if you're trying to assign a column in one dataframe to the column of another just do this:

```py
output_df['Amount'] = df['Amount']
```

Comment: which one df_output? or df? the one reading the csv, i can not change the column names

Comment: the example I showed above it's df. It doesn't look like you're trying to do anything other than rename the columns correct?

Comment: You should clarify your question, as all I can see you trying to do is to feed a loaded dataframe into an empty one the only difference being that the column 'Created (UTC)' being changed to 'Payout Date'.

Comment: thats what i was trying to do, but when printing the "empty"/second one, it would just print NaN or NAT

Comment: your problem is that the dataframe you're trying to populate doesn't have an index

Comment: it has an index, i already solved the problem but i cant post the answer because i got "answer ban" or something like that, all i needed was to not use.iloc[0]